# How to get a list of invitations to games with Facebook's Graph Api?

Tags: graph, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbjs

The list is displayed in the tab: "Game Requests" or "App Requests". How to get a list to json format?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned you can get it only for a specific application, i.e. check if the user has any requests from your application. I couldn't find anything which would return user's all requests.

You can try either `https://graph.facebook.com/User_ID/apprequests?access_token=...` or

`https://graph.facebook.com/User_ID/platformrequests?access_token=...` but the latter one *must be called with an app secret signed session*.